# Dynamic keys (using parameters) in linked locale messages in Vue's i18n

Tags: vuejs3, vue-i18n

I want to link locale messages in vue-i18n with a parameter. For example when I have a localisation file like that:

```
{
  "text": "I want to learn @:langs.{lang}",
  "langs": {
    "es": "Spanish",
    "en": "English",
    "it": "Italian"
  }
}
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
$t('text', { lang: 'es' })
```

to output this: **I want to learn Spanish**

Is it somehow possible to achieve that?

I've tried all different types of combinations and 99% of them result in compilation errors....

Answer (score -1):

`$t('text', { lang: $t('langs.es') })`

Like that.

Comment: I'd rather not include the keys in the parameters, if possible...